Google Sheets REGEXREPLACE - exclude matches based on last character
Source text:
Basic medication kit of dentistry Drugs box containing Salbutamol; Glycerol-Trinitrate; Glucagon and Adrenaline

Formula:
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(G20,"([A-Z][\w\-]*[^;])",CHAR(10)&"· $1"))

Actual Result text:
· Basic medication kit of dentistry 
· Drugs box containing 
· Salbutamol; 
· Glycerol-Trinitrate; 
· Glucagon and 
· Adrenaline

Expected Result text:
· Basic medication kit of dentistry 
· Drugs box containing Salbutamol; Glycerol-Trinitrate; 
· Glucagon and 
· Adrenaline

What I want to do is exclude matches that end with a semicolon. At the moment, in my regex formula I have [^;] which seems to have no effect.
Can this be done?

Could you please elaborate the expected results? 1) Why should items be split after Glycerol-Trinitrate;  but not after Salbutamol;? 2) Why are items split before Drugs, Glucagon, ... but not before Salbutamol?

Try \b([A-Z]\w+(?:-\w+)*\b(?:[^-;]|$))

Thanks @WiktorStribiżew
I have further simplified the regex ([A-Z]\w+\b([^-;]|$))
It is still quite difficult to understand - for me. Possible to word explain it?

I added an answer with some more hints.

You can use
\b([A-Z]\w+(?:-\w+)*\b(?:[^-;]|$))

See the regex demo
Details:

\b - a word boundary (the next letter matched should be the first letter of a word
[A-Z] - an ASCII uppercase letter
\w+ - one or more word chars
(?:-\w+)* - zero or more repetitions of - and one or more letters
\b - a word boundary
(?:[^-;]|$) - a non-capturing group matching either a character other than - and ; or end of string.

Some hints:

[\w\-]* can match a - followed with a word char, so to make the match end with a word char, a (?:-\w+)* re-vamping is required
[^;] can actually match any character other than ;, even a word char
Relying on whitespace boundaries is a crude workaround that may work in some situations, but in many cases, there are punctuation marks after a word, so I think whitespace boundaries won't help.


Slight modification to your original formula by including a non-capturing group check
=trim(regexreplace(A1,"((?:^| )[A-Z][^ ]*[^;](?: |$))",char(10)&"· $1"))

Alternate Approach:
=reduce(,split(A1," "),lambda(a,c,trim(a&if(and(regexmatch(left(c),"[A-Z]"),right(c)<>";"),char(10)&"· "," ")&c)))


splitting all the words & then joining them one at a go by keeping a check on if the word start with caps and does not end with ;


